# How to get a nice form of this integral in the form of product, so that it's easy to compute when a question is given?

Tags: calculus

Our teacher just asked us to compute $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin^{4}{x} \cos^{3}{x}~ dx}$ and just wrote it in the form of products, but I didn't understand how he wrote it so fast. So I wanted to try find a nice form , so that I can compute the product easily.

I have the integral $J_{m,n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin^{m}{x} \cos^{n}{x}~ dx}$.

I have already derived that $J_{m,n}=\frac{n-1}{m+n} \cdot J_{m,n-2}=\frac{m-1}{m+n} J_{m-2,n}$

I am trying to combine both, and get the recursion to go to $J_{1,0}/J_{0,1}/J_{0,0}/J_{1,1}$ in the form of a continued product, but the way I'm doing it is first use the first relation to go to
$J_{m,0}/J_{m,1}$ then again compute till $J_{1,0}/J_{0,1}/J_{0,0}/J_{1,1}$. By taking cases on the powers of m and n. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to deal with the recrusion, because im just plugging in values from $2m/2n$ and going till $1/0$. It would be nice if someone can write the final forms down.

Comment: Why don't you write $\sin^4 (x) \cos^3(x)=\sin^4(x) (1-\sin^2(x) \,d(\sin(x))$

Comment: Your method of dealing with $J_{m,n}$ is fine when $n-m$ is divisible by $2.$ If the difference is odd, one of the powers is odd, hence it is more convenient to make substitution $u=\sin x$ when $n$ is odd and $u=\cos x$ when $m$ is odd, as proposed by @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Yes, I can solve them using the normal methods. We are learning reduction formulas, so i need to find a nice form for the recursion which is given. The question given was just an example our teacher gave us, and showed how to calculate the definite integral in a very short amount of time. He said it was "walli's formula", but i couldnt find the same form in the wikipedia page.